# Ability to offer a bounty right now

Tags: discussion, bounty

Why not to make bounty available from the very creation of the question? I read the question on [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/why-cant-i-just-offer-a-bounty-for-a-question-right-off-the-bat) and I got the idea.

> They didn't want a bounty to interfere with the 'normal' method of
>   asking/answering questions. If you're allowed to offer it right away,
>   then it has the potential to create an economy where people only focus
>   on questions with bounties.
>
> It's important to note that it's very rare (over 90% of questions are
>   answered) for your question not to be answered. As far as getting it
>   answered quickly, well that depends on what time you ask your question
>   (All times UTC).

Everything is nice, but this was ancient 2009 and there were not so many questions posted every minute as it is now. Someone who post a post hard question about javascript, java, c#, python, php or any other popular tag, have a high chance of being ignored if he was not lucky enough to get an answer in the first 30 minutes.

He is just being piled with 100 simpler questions. So you end up waiting and waiting till you can give the bounty till some experts really can check your question.

So, with all respect to 2009, does it make sense to change something in 2014? We are already in economy where a lot of people are chasing easy questions. Can it be so bad if someone with earned reputation can give it to person who solves his problem?

Comment: Related: [its-time-to-remove-the-bounty-delay](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210384/)

Comment: Is there a real issue here? Have you ever asked a good question without getting a satisfactory answer? Sure, SO has a higher questions/time ratio, but the amount of good questions worth answering/time ratio has dwindled (IMO). People who are keen to answer good questions may just skip all <= 0 score questions, and you are then more likely to get an answer than before. Also remember that "Newest" is not the only question queue, your question will also stay listed in the "Active" queue as long as you nurture it.

Comment: (cont.) And besides all that, in the current system, offering a bounty prevents a question from being closed by the community. That's a huge loophole that would have to be fixed before even considering your request.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté good is relative term. What good for you most probably is not good for someone else. Some questions can not even get 1 vote because they are not "should I use == or === in JS" kind of questions. Also what do you mean by nurture it? Doing unnecessary edits to make it active? I got your point with closed by community. I did not know about it. Thanks

Comment: @SalvadorDali Well, I believe that "good", in the context of an answer, is an answer that solves and fully explains the issue and the solution. In the context of a question, a good question would be an on-topic and clear question with enough data to reproduce the issue (when applicable), and not too localized (a question that other people can relate to). By "nurture" it I mean edit in your progress, add info requested in the comments, etc.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté then I believe yes, I have some questions like this. There is no way to edit your progress if only few people viewed it.

Comment: Oh I see. Guess I just have not made enough questions and have been lucky enough to don't experience that yet. `=]` As a last resort, I'd sneakily drop the question in the language's chat room -- but don't just blatantly ask for help with it (which is often frowned upon). If your question is technically good, something in the lines of "Why haven't I received any answer to this question?" is an acceptable way to ask for directions improving your question while directing some answerers to it.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté thank you for suggestion.

Comment: you can always just keep editing your question to get it moved to the top of the active list